# Stored Procedure return value based on foreign key

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables, a User table with some information including a foreign key to a Rol table, and the Rol table itself which contains the id and name.

I a populating a DataSet using the following procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pa_select_usuario]



AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT id_usuario, nombre_1, nombre_2, apellido_1,apellido_2, genero, correo, 
                                         cedula, telefono ,rol, estado 

    FROM beca_seguridad_usuarios



END
```

The only problem is that in the table I'm filling the rol value is a int (the Id of the Rol table), whereas I would prefer it to show the name.

Is there a way to return all those value but instead of the rol field sending a parameter @rol_name?
Where @rol_name = name from the table Rol with the matching ID

Obviously wrong but something like:

```
SELECT id_usuario, nombre_1, nombre_2, apellido_1,apellido_2, genero, correo, 
                                     cedula, telefono ,estado

FROM beca_seguridad_usuarios


SELECT nombre FROM beca_seguridad_roles WHERE id_rol = beca_seguridad_usuarios.rol


Return id_usuario, nombre_1, nombre_2, apellido_1,apellido_2, genero, correo, 
                                     cedula, telefono, nombre, estado
```

I'm sorry if he answer seems obvious, I'm kinda new to SQL, so any advice would be great.

EDIT:

This is how I am filling the Table on Visual Studio, in case it is relevant:

```
public IEnumerable<Usuario> GetAll()
{
    List<Usuario> lstUsuario = null;

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    DataSet ds = DBAccess.ExecuteSPWithDS(ref cmd, "pa_select_usuario");

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        lstUsuario = new List<Usuario>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            lstUsuario.Add(new Usuario
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id_usuario"]),
                Nombre = dr["nombre_1"].ToString(),
                SegundoNombre = dr["nombre_2"].ToString(),
                PrimerApellido = dr["apellido_1"].ToString(),
                SegundoApellido = dr["apellido_2"].ToString(),
                Genero = dr["genero"].ToString(),
                Correo = dr["correo"].ToString(),
                Cedula = Convert.ToInt32(dr["cedula"]),
                Telefono = dr["telefono"].ToString(),
                Rol = Convert.ToInt32(dr["rol"]),
                Estado = Convert.ToInt32(dr["estado"])
            });
        }
    }

    return lstUsuario;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can JOIN the two tables in a single query to return the desired result set with the related data:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.pa_select_usuario
AS

SELECT 
      bsu.id_usuario
    , bsu.nombre_1
    , bsu.nombre_2
    , bsu.apellido_1
    , bsu.apellido_2
    , bsu.genero
    , bsu.correo
    , bsu.cedula
    , bsu.telefono
    , bsr.nombre
    , bsu.estado
FROM beca_seguridad_usuarios AS bsu
JOIN beca_seguridad_roles AS bsr ON
    bsr.id_rol = bsu.rol;

GO
```